# Why Xdebug Start Debugging (Launch Browser) is missing?

Tags: xdebug, sublimetext3

Yesterday it works fine. Today I use ctrl + F8 to add a breakpoint and press ctrl + p , x d ,there is no Xdebug Start Debugging (Launch Browser) any more, only Xdebug Start Debugging .
Why where should I change? any information will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the current .sublime-project file and save the project again.

Project -> Save Project As...

Then insert again in the .sublime-project file the code below:

```
{
  "folders":
  [
    {
        "follow_symlinks": true,
        "path": "."
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "xdebug": {
         "url": "http://my.local.website/",
    }
  }
}
```

** Be sure to change the "url" to your site base URL.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to provide a `url` for xdebug.

For example, say your project `documentroot` is located at `http://localhost/myproject/public_html`, then in `SublimeText3` goto `Project -> Edit Project` and enter a `url` value for `xdebug`.

For example, my project file currently looks like:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "/var/www/html/myproject"
        }
    ],
    /* below is the important part ;) */
    "settings": {
        "xdebug": {
            "url": "http://localhost/myproject/public_html",
        }
    }
}
```

Once this is saved (you may need to restart SublimeText?) then the option to open in 'browser' should appear.

Also you can set the `url` field in the user settings for xdebug (`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Xdebug -> Settings User`) but then this would make the `url` open on all projects and not just the current one.